# What is the collective name for the seas of Indonesia?

Tags: oceanography, geography

The seas in Indonesia or Sunda Shelf or Southeast Asia separates the Indian Ocean and Pacific Ocean. The seas in Indonesia itself are broken into many parts due to presence of islands such as Sunda islands, Philippines etc. Examples include Java Sea, Celebes Sea, Banda Sea, Flores Sea etc.

Is there a collective term to name the seas of Indonesia as a whole region???

Comment: Can you add (part of) a map and indicate what area you mean?

Comment: A more generic term might be Indonesian territorial waters

Answer (score 3):

I've always known it as the *Maritime Continent*, as in,

Neale and Slingo (2003) [The Maritime Continent and Its Role in the Global Climate: A GCM Study](https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0442(2003)016%3C0834:TMCAIR%3E2.0.CO;2), J. Clim, doi:10.1175/1520-0442(2003)016%3C0834:TMCAIR%3E2.0.CO;2

But that has an atmospheric perspective; it refers to the ocean and the land, because they're both important for the meteorology of the region.  There may be another name for just the watery bits in between the land.

Comment: @Fred Your term sounds _less_ generic to me, i.e., it's a specific definition in law. It may also be more the sort of thing that the OP is after.

Comment: Apologies, my comment was placed in wrong location. It was meant to be a comment for the question, not your answer. I'll move it to were it should be.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single term for all of the seas of Indonesia but there are the main seas that make up the archipelago that are, The Karimata Strait, The Java sea, the Arafura Sea, The straits of Malacca, Karimata and Sunda, the Celebes sea, the Sulu sea etc. There is a collective name for the archipelago though, the Nusantara archipelago (excluding the Phillipines and western Malaysia)
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallacea#/media/